# Form items poitioning issue

Tags: html, css

I have a form where there is only textfield and a button. They are on the same row and first comes the texttfield and then a button on the right. The thing is, that the button expands based on the caption on it and the textfield must fill the rest of the place. To achieve this I used something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        #search_form {
        width:500px;
        }
        #search_button_container {
        float: right;
        }

        #search_field_container {
        overflow: hidden;
        }

        #search_field {
        width:92%;
        }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="search_form">
        <div>
        <div id="search_button_container">
        <input type="submit" value="Search" id="search_submit" />
        </div>

        <div id="search_field_container">
        <input id="search_field" name="search_field" type="search" />                                       
        </div>                                  
       </div>                                                          
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

In this markup the button is the first item, but due to the float=right on the page it is located on the right side, which is what I want, but this messes the tabindex order. When tabbing, firstly the button will be in the focus and then the textfield, but I need the textfield to be the first.

Note: I can't add tabindex=1 to textfield and tabindex=2 to the button, since there are other elements above and beyond this search form and the tabindex must move from top to bottom.

Is there another way to position the elements the way I want or reorder the tabindex. The best solution in my case is to use another stylings to achieve the desired result, but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

A CSS table uses the same algorithm as an HTML table except it has nothing to do with it, semantically speaking. It's just **rendered** visually the same way.

Then you can have 2 cells that combined have 100% width and still have content of each one that adapt to the lengths of each other. Search input will be shorter if the submit button is longer.

Here's a **fiddle** demonstrating it: http://jsfiddle.net/4JvRV/1/
Let me know if it doesn't work in Chrome.
**Compatibility**: IE8+
**Fallbacks** for IE7-: IE7 and IE6 will see a shorter sear... err text input, perfectly acceptable IMHO. Or you can decide to have a 100% width and display them on 2 lines if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks, but I have to support IE7 and higher.

Comment: I already indicated fallbacks for IE7 that seems perfectly acceptable to me. It won't hinder anybody from using the form input. But if you need pixel perfect rendering in IE7, then say goodbye to semantics and use an HTML table where `td` would be what I tagged with `p`. And to anybody willing to downvoting me for this blasphemy, please also provide a solution that works in IE7 with all the constraints added by @Hayk ;)

Comment: I'd convince my employer that supporting IE7 is to expensive. Because it is.

Comment: I can't convince the customer, they give us very-very strict requirenents. And by the way I can't use tables as well, thus the question is still open, and now I'm not even sure if there is a solution att all.

Answer (score 0):

Put the button after the text field and float the text field to the left.

Comment: Probably I didn't explain myself clearly. I want the button on the right, near the form right border and the textfield must FILL the rest space on the left. You can copy the code I posted and put a longer text on button caption(change the value attribute) and you will understand what I want.

Comment: I'd make the button fix-width, even though that's apparently not what you want. I'm sorry, I'm out of answers here. What I can say is that I think it's a bad idea to hide portions of the text input with `overflow: hidden;` And I must also say that the only way to make the tab order correct, without using `tabindex`,  is to put the input first in the document.

Comment: Thank you anyway for taking part in the discussion.